# Is there a way to install only the base Fedora system?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I'd like to install a base Fedora system meaning without all the other programs/applications that come when installing a Gnome/KDE/XFCE spins. How do I do this?

This is the first time I'd be installing Fedora and I'm quite accustomed to Arch Linux so I want the same approach, or similar approach of building from the base install up to the system of my preference.

I've been reading the documentation and came across using the boot options `linux text` but I don't think this will install a base Fedora system, just that the installation menu system will be in text mode, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed Fedora 15 recently, there was an option for a minimal install.  I just clicked that radio button.  Other choices were (if I remember correctly) Desktop Setup, Server Setup, Developer Setup.

Comment: Well, I didn't get the said choices when I installed the XFCE spin of Fedora 17. So now I have a XFCE Fedora install. I'll try to run the LiveDVD using the default ISO and see if I get those options.

Comment: Okay, I was using the Live CD version of Fedora 17 which, as I've read, doesn't give the user much options with regard to installing packages. So I downloaded the netinstall version of the installer and I was able to get the Minimal Install radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

Opting to select the packages at install time and then unselecting all of them will remove most extras. If you need an even more minimal install then you'll need to use the AOS kickstart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of any links to where I can download a pre-made kickstart file to install a base Fedora 17 system?

Comment: Pre-made, no. But [this](https://fedorahosted.org/spin-kickstarts/browser/fedora-aos.ks) gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Get Fedora LiveDVD， you can choose minimal install(Terminal only or with gnome/kde)